# LED Display character set

Tags: iphone, bitmap, character

I am looking for character sets to display each character in my LED Display Board.

Normally I have to put all these characters together in an array of booleans, for example H and A:

```
bool[] H = { 1,0,0,0,0,1,   bool[] A = { 0,0,1,1,0,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,1,                0,1,0,0,1,0,
         1,1,1,1,1,1,                0,1,1,1,1,0,
         1,0,0,0,0,1,                1,0,0,0,0,1,
         1,0,0,0,0,1 }               1,0,0,0,0,1 }
```

I think there should be such collections already available in the internet, but under the seach keys with *character set* I found nothing. So a list with possibly many characters expressed with this bitmap format.

Do you have a tip for me. Would save me a lot of stupid word :)

Thanks you very much for the help. I appreciate it.

Regards, 
Chris

Answer (score 1):

check out this site: [character-set-generator](http://expat.dyndns.org/arduino/character-set-generator/)

[image]

Is site great for you.

Comment: thank you my friend...I don't know why I didn't find this site:)

Comment: So I checked it out. Do you a unicode character set, because I need a lot more characters. Would be great to hear from yiu

Answer (score 0):

To import fonts in a C code for LED display, we need to convert bitmap of a font into byte arrays so that it can be easily superimposed onto the video memory of Display.
For that you will find number of tools to fits your requirement.
but best format of byte code is given below to be used in LED display code:

```
{0x07e0, 0x1ff8, 0x3ffc, 0x600e, 0x8001, 0x0000 }, // Byte code for A
{0x8001, 0x4006, 0x7ffc, 0x3ff8, 0x0fe0, 0x0000 }, // Byte code for B
{0x0018, 0x003e, 0x003e, 0x003e, 0x003e, 0x0018, 0x0000 },  // Byte code for W
```

Some times in back I had made such custom build application on VC++ platform. It generates byte code for bitmap in above form.

I can share that app if you really indeed.

By using such bytecode formats you can easily achieve LED display sign such as shown in following images:

http://www.ledsignsdisplays.com/indoor-led-signs.html

http://photonplay.com/indoor-led-display.html